# What's the most efficient setup for hosting a “passthrough” string manipulator?

Tags: regex, node.js, nginx

**Server A** needs to send raw string data to **Server B** via http API calls.
**Server B** must parse and manipulate raw string data and then send resulting key/value pairs to **Server C**, via http API calls.
**Server A** cannot talk to **Server C** directly.

The operations to take place are:

1. Reception of string data (~8k of poorly formatted XML)
2. Manipulation of string data
3. Sending of string data

**All of this must happen at scale, meaning thousands of times per second, from hundreds of different clients.**

Perhaps nginx as a host, since it's great at concurrency? If so, what's the most efficient language to use behind it for the text manipulation, parsing and sending?

I also thought node might be a good option, since it has all the string manipulation functions built-in, as well as the protocols for sending and receiving data.

Very interested in hearing thoughts on the best way to approach this.

Comment: Node is great for execution of tasks that have a lot of blocked network waiting, not really for CPU intensive tasks (as your question seems to imply).

Comment: @MartinKonecny That's a good point. I didn't consider the text manipulation to be CPU intensive, but I suppose it could be. I'm talking about parsing about 8k worth of text at a time.